# How-To?: Setting up Bokeh w/ Redis Backend

Tags: python, python-2.7, redis, bokeh

*Note from maintainers: This question is obsolete. See [Running a Bokeh Server](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html) for information about running a modern Bokeh server (which has no dependency on Redis)*

---

I'm trying to set up my bokeh server to use Redis for the backend.  I followed the instructions at http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.8.2/docs/installation.html#install-windows, using the second link.  However, when I run `bokeh-server --backend=redis` in my cmd line, I get the error `ImportError: No module named 'redis'`.  This is understandable, as within the path, there's no redis.exe per se, but rather redis-service.exe, redis-server.exe, etc.  I tried different variations, to no avail.

How can I set up the server to run with redis as the backend?

For reference, I'm running python 2.7 (Anaconda), Win 7, redis 2.4.6, bokeh 0.7.1

Comment: I think you need redis python package installed anyway, just install it using pip or easy_install. As I understand you have redis server installed, but looks like python redis client library is missed.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**: As of Bokeh `0.11` (January 2016) Bokeh no longer requires Redis, even optionally.

---

As @artemdevel pointed out, the import error is referring to the redis python client.

As you are using anaconda:

```
$ conda install redis-py
```

For non conda users `pip install redis` or `easy_install redis`.

It's a little confusing because `conda install redis` installs the actual redis binary and the python client library is `redis-py` for install, but then in python code, you just use `import redis`. And to add to the confusion, my understanding is that `conda install redis` is not available for windows users!

Answer (score 2):

Two steps:

1) Install Redis for Windows.

I was able to do this via an MSI installer on the MSOpenTech GitHub page.
https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis

2) Install the python client.

This can be installed through the conda-forge channel like so

```
conda install redis-py -c conda-forge
```